# How limit return elements from Express Router

Tags: reactjs, express, backend, mern

I have many movies in my API and I want to return one part of them, I work in MERN stack and I don't have any idea for do that, I want to pagination my API with Express framework.
This is my code:

```
 const router = require('express').Router()
let Movie = require('../models/movie.model')


router.route('/:limit').get((req,res)=>{

    let limit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 5

    Movie.find().limit(limit)
        .then(movies=>res.json(movies))
        .catch(err=>res.status(400).json('Error: '+err))
})
```

For example this is the url that I want "/movies?limit=20"

Comment: What's problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use skip and limit. you Url will be **/movies?limit=2&skip=2**

```
let limit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 5
let skip = parseInt(req.query.skip) || 0

Movie.find().skip(skip).limit(limit)
```

**OR**

```
Movie.find(query, fields, { skip, limit }, function(err, results) { ... });
```